# LINQ grouping to more than one group

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T, List<U>>> Data;
```

or that could be expressed also as

```
Dictionary<T, List<U>> GroupedA
```

That is given a T it might belong to one or more U. I want
to invert this so I can lookup U and find all the associated
T's in the structure

```
Dictionary<U, List<T>> GroupedB;
```

Trying to think of a neat LINQ expression to invert the dictionary.

**EDIT**

Actually the correct answer below shows that what I really want is

```
ILookup<U, T>
```

rather than

```
Dictionary<U, List<T>>
```

Comment: The IEnumerable<T> interface can only have one generic type parameter. What's the actual type of `Data`?

Comment: My bad. Sorry it should be an Enumerable of Tuple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//Populating data
Dictionary<int, List<string>> GroupedA = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

GroupedA.Add(1, new List<string>{"1","2","3"});
GroupedA.Add(2, new List<string>{"1","32","3","4"});
GroupedA.Add(3, new List<string>{"1","52","43","4"});


//Inverting data
ILookup<string, int> GroupedB = 
       GroupedA.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select(val => new{pair.Key, val}))
               .ToLookup(pair => pair.val, pair => pair.Key);



//Printing data 
var pairs = GroupedB.Select(pair => string.Format("{0} : {1}", pair.Key, string.Join(",", pair)));

Console.WriteLine (string.Join(Environment.NewLine, pairs));
```

prints:

```
1 : 1,2,3 
2 : 1 
3 : 1,2 
32 : 2 
4 : 2,3 
52 : 3 
43 : 3
```

Comment: ToLookup is the key. For those wishing to understand I found a blog post on the difference between ToLookup and ToDictionary http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/02/12/linq-tolookup-vs-todictionary/

Comment: Your question explicitly asks for a `Dictionary<U, List<T>>`. `ToLookup` doesn't provide that.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, sorry, I've used OPs words `I want to invert this so I can lookup U and find all the associated T's in the structure` as problem statement, which can be achieved perfectly using `ILookup<string, int>`. Sorry if I did something bad.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: I don't oppose to your answer. It is good. I oppose to the OPs comments on your and my answer. The OP obviously has only limited understanding of LINQ when he says that `ToDictionary` is the wrong method to use.

Comment: I'll mark Daniel's as the correct one as he got in first but thanks for the various techniques.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Thanks for that, but please accept the answer whose code you use. If you don't explicitly need a `Dictionary<U, List<T>>`, Ilya's code is definitly more elegant.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure which one I'll use at the moment. Still trying to digest the exact difference between the two. Both are correct but can't give two ticks :(

Comment: The difference is that `ToLookup` returns an `ILookup<TKey, TValue>` which is basically a dictionary for the special case where you have more than one value per key.

Comment: ok. i've decided to go with ToLookup which solves a number of problems I've had with dictionaries lately. Thanks all :)

Comment: Curious, looking through my codebase I had an implementation of a mutable lookup but not implementing ILookup. I cleaned it up and posted it here in case anybody is interested. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16790538/158285

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Data.SelectMany(tuple => tuple.Item2.Select(u => new { U = u, T = tuple.Item1 }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.U)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.T).ToList());
```

Complete test case code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using FluentAssertions;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Class1
    {
        //Populating data
        Dictionary<int, List<string>> GroupedA = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        public Class1()
        {
            GroupedA.Add(1, new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" });
            GroupedA.Add(2, new List<string> { "1", "32", "3", "4" });
            GroupedA.Add(3, new List<string> { "1", "52", "43", "4" });
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ToDictionarySpec()
        {
            var data = GroupedA.Select(v => Tuple.Create(v.Key, v.Value));

            var r = data.SelectMany(tuple => tuple.Item2.Select(u => new { U = u, T = tuple.Item1 }))
            .GroupBy(x => x.U)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.T).ToList());

            //Printing data 
            var pairs = r.Select(pair => string.Format("{0} : {1}", pair.Key, string.Join(",", pair.Value)));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, pairs));
        }


    }
}
```

outputs

```
Test Name:  ToDictionarySpec
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:  
1 : 1,2,3
2 : 1
3 : 1,2
32 : 2
4 : 2,3
52 : 3
43 : 3
```

Comment: I think the final type there will just be ``Dictionary<U,T>`` not ``Dictionary<U, List<T>>``

Comment: GroupBy will only allow members to be part of one group :). Key problem is that an item can belong to many groups.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. Have you tested the new version?

Comment: Think ``Dictionary<Movie, List<Actor>>`` to ``Dictionary<Actor, List<Movie>>`` It's a many to many relationship which I want to invert.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: I understood that. Again: Did you test it?

Comment: Don't need to. IIlya above got the correct answer using ToLookup. ToDictionary is the wrong API call.